# Cache memory on hit, no data stored

Tags: memory, cache

So, I have a question about the cache memory, i know that if the tag matches the data will be retrieved, but what happens if the current address has the same tag with others but in that place, in my picture (10) where the FF would be, but in our case it's not. The tags are the same so would be a hit, but there is no data there, what happens? Is there another check, where validates the data that needs to be retrieved? And would just skip and will check for the data from the main memory.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add some context to your question.

Comment: I agree with @Transistor. It isn't normally possible for a cache line to be only partially valid. It's either all valid or all invalid.

Comment: I think you give me more credit than I deserve. I have little idea what the question is about. What's a tag? Is this for a particular CPU type? Where has the problem come up?

Comment: Ok so i’ll give more context, my bad. So if we assume that values 39, 3D, 1A where cached,ok? They all have the same tag, right? And now i want to check the value for the address 1100 0101 0110, the tag bits will match cause we have those 3  values cached, would be a hit, but at 10, we have no data, what happens?

Comment: *"They all have the same tag, right?"* Wrong! The values 39, 3D and 1A **are** the tag values and they all differ. They are accessed by the same (partial) address but the partial address plus the tags make up the total address.

Comment: And why they are on the same line? 1100 0101 01, they need to have something in common..and i knew that the tags would be.

Comment: They have the same **partial** address in common. That part of the address which goes to the tag memory. There are four on a line because you have there a four-way cache. I suggest you start looking at how a one-way cache works and work up from there.

Comment: @Sp1tfire: Welcome to EE.SE. Tip 1: It's important that all the info is in the question and not sprinkled through the comments. By "context" I meant where in the world of electronics this problem arises. I know what cache memory is but is this related to particular CPU types. Tip 2: Try to address each legitimate point raised in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, but i’m just learning abou memory caches in general and i had some few questions. It’s my first post, sry.

Comment: are you designing a CPU, and your question is about pre-fetch cache?

Answer (score 0):

The 'tag' coming out of the cache tag memory is in effect a partial address. It is that part of the address which is not used in the tag memory (minus the cache line width bits).

Assume a 16 bits address and a 1K cache<sup>+</sup>. The 1K Tag memory requires 10 bits. Which means we have 6 unused address bits. The tag memory will then be 1Kx6 bits wide. The 6 data bits coming out will be compared against the unused 6 address bits. Thus the total will always check the *whole* of the address.

It gets more complex if you have more then one 'way' or if a cache entry points to more then one memory entry (The so called line-width of the cache).

<sup>+</sup><sub>I assume the cache line width is single memory entry.</sub>

---

I can't read the text so I am having some problems, but what I see is that **the diagram is totally wrong!**

Not only is it missing the TAG *valid* bits, also the whole address handling is **dead wrong**.  The address should be split into two parts, one going to the address of the tag memory the other to a comparator using the data coming out of the tag memory. In the diagram they put two bits into "selectie date" but the data in the tag memory is shown as 8 bits.

I recommend you do NOT look at the diagram at all but find a better one.
Try [this](https://www.verilog.pro/download/modules/cache/cache.pdf) document.

Comment: So if you cache only one value an example would be address 1100 0110 0001 with the value D5, how the cache memory would look? wouldn’t be valid only the cell from 01 postion? an the rest wouldn’t have any value

Comment: I will edit my answer.